# Unexpected huge MOSFETs power consumption

Tags: power, mosfet, current, power-consumption, powermosfet

I have 2 MOSFETs :

[image]

NMOS -->

```
     Ref :BSZ520 
  Rds_on : 52 mohms
```

PMOS -->

```
     Ref :IRF9640 
  Rds_on : 500 mohms
```

My load (Cact1) is drawing around +/- 250 mA. I calculated the power dissipation with P= R*I² which gives me the following results :

BSZ520  -->

```
       P = 3 mW
```

IRF9640 -->

```
       P = 31 mW
```

Then why when I use ALT+right click, LTspice gives me hundreds of watts? I hope it's not relevant.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123606/discussion-on-question-by-af2021-unexpected-huge-mosfets-power-consumption).

Comment: Sounds about right for an amplifier that deep in Class A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> LTspice gives me hundreds of watts? I hope it's not relevant.

Unfortunately, it is relevant. You have shoot-through, i.e. current flowing through both transistors at the same time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9OC88.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- [Datasheet for BSZ520N15NS3](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/12v-300v-n-channel-power-mosfet/bsz520n15ns3-g/#!?fileId=db3a30432662379201266a0dd612226c)
- [Datasheet for IRF9640](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91086/sihf9640.pdf)

With the biasing resistors as in the schematic, significant current flows through the transistors even when the input voltage is 0.

[image]
[image]

By decreasing the 5k\$\Omega\$ resistors to 2k\$\Omega\$, the lost current became dramatically reduced.

[image]

There may be some cross-over distortion, but it is "small" for some definition of "small". If this is for audio purposes, it *might* be audible. My own ability to discern "high fidelity" is rather weak.

[image]

However, I simulated at 5V, 2V and 1V, and even at a 1V input, cross-over distortion is not visible in the graph.
[image]

Comment: Does it mean that my biaising is not correct ? Because i need the mosfets to react quickly to avoid cross over distortion

Comment: Yes, you are biasing the MOSFETs too strongly. Unfortunately, MOSFET threshold voltages vary from device to device, so it is hard to get an _exact_ value for the R7/8 resistors that will be "ideal". I decreased them to 2k in a simulation, and the shoot-through fell to micro-amps. The cross-over distortion was not _visible_ to me on the output voltage plots. However, it may significant to you, especially if this is an audio circuit. Some people may or may not notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort ! I tried your suggestion on Ltspice but unfortunately the distortion is not acceptable ( and you guessed right, it is for audio, so i have to get very clean signals)

Comment: If it were not for the fact that over-current will make your mosfets toast, I would suggest a trimmer pot (variable resistor), so you could adjust the bias to just the right spot. Unfortunately, one movement of the trimmer pot too far, and poof!

Comment: haha i'm actually trying my best to avoid the "poof" (i was about to make the circuit and test it but fortunately you all stopped me before it was too late :D )

Comment: Also be aware that the exact bias resistor value will depend on the individual MOSFET characteristics so you can't just set it by design. Furthermore it may vary with temperature in the right direction for thermal runaway. Not an easy problem : you might consider using those current sense resistors R12,R16 to control the bias voltages with a negative feedback loop (perhaps by replacing those 100K resistors with controlled current sources) but it's not a trivial piece of design.